# How to determine the rotation of an objects relative to another?

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, image-processing, opencv

I have two images. One with a rotated object, one with a non-rotated object.

How can I measure the degree of rotation of the second object with respect to the first using Python?

I tried doing thresholding to extract features and finding the contours, but I am lost on how to go to the next steps. A is the original image and B is the rotated image.

[image]

Comment: Pca will work here

Comment: Will I have to use a large dataset or couple images will work for PCA?